# How to generate unique keys for a hashtable, and recycle deleted keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

For example, I need 10 objects stored in the hashmap.

So it creates keys 1,2,3,4,5

Then when I'm finished with '3', it deletes the whole entry and key for '3'. Making that key able to re-used  for new object mappings -if I run over, via integer overflow or something.

Thoughts?

```
public static HashMap <GameKey, GameState> myMap  = new HashMap<GameKey, GameState>();
int i=0;

public void MapNewGameState(Gamestate gs){

myMap.add(i, gameStateA);
i++;
}


myMap.remove("3");
//Now I want to be sure that my MapNewGameState function is able to eventually map a new GameState to the key "3" later on,
```

this is more a question about if HashMaps can be used in this way.

Comment: You've probably to handle hash collisions.

Comment: I've edited the submission to reflect my goal in code better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you propose a key-pool where you get a key and if you don't need it anymore you put it back into the pool? If so this doesnt really make much sense since it adds complexity to your code but no other benefits (usually you pool something thats expensive to create or hold). And usually you want to recycle the value not the key?

To create truly (practical) unique keys use [`UUID.randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29), whith this you don't have to worry about keys.

Comment: That would be perfect if it works.  So UUID.randomUUID() will avoid any instances of collisions altogether?

Comment: Yes, check out the wikipedia article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier "In other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%"

Comment: Well, that's bloody brilliant.  Thanks!